# Do rvalues decay silently?

Tags: c++, c++20, rvalue-reference

```
std::vector foo( std::vector && rval )
{
    return std::move( rval );
}
```

If a function expects an rvalue reference but gets something else - e.g. a const reference or a temporary or whatever different from `std::move(vec)`, will it silently make a copy instead of throwing an error or even a warning?

Comment: A temporary can be bound to an rvalue reference. There is no copy to be made. An lvalue reference, const or not, cannot. Trying to pass one is a diagnosable constraint violation.

Comment: "*If a function expects an rvalue reference but gets something else*" That's not a possibility. If a function takes an X, then it *gets* an X. Sometimes, a Y will need to be coerced into an X, but the function gets the X. You can't pass a `const&` to a function that takes a `&&` without doing an explicit cast, in which case you are the one responsible for the viability of those operations. And temporaries naturally bind to rvalue references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S() { }
    S(const S& other) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    S(S&& other) { std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl; }
}; 

int foo( S && rval )
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    S s1;
    foo (s1);
}
```

Copying S'es is not silent. So, what happens when you try to compile this?

This [happens](https://godbolt.org/z/5W9vYna4c) (Godbolt):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:10: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'S&&' to lvalue of type 'S'
   17 |     foo (s1);
      |          ^~
<source>:9:15: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int foo(S&&)'
    9 | int foo( S && rval )
      |          ~~~~~^~~~
```

So, the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 1):

If a function that expect rvalue ref gets const ref then compiler gives error.  If a function that expect rvalue ref gets const then compiler gives error again.

If you also define a function that expect const rvalue ref and const ref with std::move is sent (std::move(const &)) then it works. However, it is not reasonable to define a function that expect a const rvalue ref because that means to steal from const read-only.

It is possible and reasonable to send temp value to the function that expect rvalue ref.